# Get Build Status from Azure Pipeline using azure-pipeline.yaml file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-build-task

How to configure azure-pipeline.yaml file in post build to get the build status? I have to get the current build status of the pipeline by using `azure-devops-rest-api` or `azure-devops-node-api` within the azure-pipeline.yaml file.

Please help!

Comment: you want to check if a status x do something?

Comment: @LeoBL Just to get the status like Success or Failure within `azure-pipeline.yaml` file.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS what do you mean within the yaml file?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I'm trying to get status info in the post build.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS Do you want to add a build task in the yaml that checks the build status and then what?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yeah. It would be helpful to me, if you point out some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to configure azure-pipeline.yaml file in post build to get the build status?

We could use the REST API [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the detailed build info:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitions}&api-version=5.1
```

In the YAML, we could add a powershell task to get the build result, like:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType : inline
   script: |
     $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionID}&api-version=5.1"
     $connectionToken="Your PAT Here"
     $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

       $buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get


       $BuildResult= $buildPipeline.value.result | Select-Object -first 1


       Write-Host This is Build Result: $BuildResult
```

We list all the build result for the specify definitions, then use `Select-Object -first 1` to get the latest build result.

[image]

As test, use the REST API, we could get the result of **latest build** for the current pipeline, **but we could not get the results of the build we are performing this time**.

Besides, there is a [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), which we could check the get the current build status of the pipeline by the Predefined variables `Agent.JobStatus`, so I add a command line task to output this value in YAML:

```
- script: |
   echo $(Agent.JobStatus)
```

This variable could get the current build status.

Hope this helps.