# azure devops - yaml pipeline stage to depend on other pipeline completion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline 'A' which has two stages- dev, prod. After dev environment finishes I want prod stage to be triggered only if pipeline 'B' is ran successfully. I want stage 'prod' of pipeline 'A' to be dependent on pipeline 'B'. Is this feasible?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get Pipeline B result in stage `dev` (link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485675/14996050)), and set it as variable, in the `prod` stage, evaluate the variable value to determine the stage to run or not(link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable)).

Code sample as below:

```
stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
  - job: DevJob
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: GetpipelineBresult
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{pipelineBProject}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={definitionid}&api-version=5.1"
            $personalToken = "$(PAT)"
            $token =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
            $header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}
            $buildPipeline= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method Get
            $BuildResult= $buildPipeline.value.result | Select-Object -first 1
            Write-Host This is Build Result: $BuildResult
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Buildresult;isOutput=true]$BuildResult"

- stage: Prod
  condition: eq(dependencies.Dev.outputs['DevJob.GetpipelineBresult.Buildresult'], 'succeeded')
  dependsOn: Dev
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - script: echo job Prod
```

Pipeline B result: succeeded
[image]

Pipeline B result: not succeeded(cancel, failed..)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Intasll this Azure DevOps Extension

[image]

2.In your Dev stage, add Trigger Build task to ensure you could trigger pipeline B and check the latest build result of pipeline B.

[image]

3.Create the Generic Service Connection.

[image]

4.Use Invoke REST API in Environment Approvals and checks.

[image]

API: GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/latest/%7Bdefinition%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

5.After check pass, second stage will depend on the success build of Pipeline B.

```
trigger:
- none
stages:
 - stage: Dev
   jobs:
    - job: CI
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-latest
      steps:
        - task: TriggerBuild@4
          inputs:
            definitionIsInCurrentTeamProject: true
            buildDefinition: 'PipelineB'
            queueBuildForUserThatTriggeredBuild: true
            ignoreSslCertificateErrors: false
            useSameSourceVersion: false
            useCustomSourceVersion: false
            useSameBranch: true
            waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: false
            storeInEnvironmentVariable: false
            authenticationMethod: 'Personal Access Token'
            password: 'PAT'
            enableBuildInQueueCondition: false
            dependentOnSuccessfulBuildCondition: false
            dependentOnFailedBuildCondition: false
            checkbuildsoncurrentbranch: false
            failTaskIfConditionsAreNotFulfilled: false
        
 - stage: Prod
   dependsOn: Dev
   jobs:
    - deployment: CD
      environment: {EnvironmentName}
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-latest
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
              steps:
                - task: CmdLine@2
                  inputs:
                    script: |
                      echo Write your commands here
                      
                      echo Hello world
```

[image]